# Ionic native camera plugins conflicting

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I have installed the plugin `cordova-plugin-camera-preview` [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera-preview/). After installing this, if I run `ionic cordova build android`, the app builds fine.

However, I also need to use the plugin `phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner` [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/barcode-scanner/) so I have installed this as well. Now when I try to run `ionic cordova build android`, the build fails with the following error:

```
    Error:
    Element uses-feature#android.hardware.camera at AndroidManifest.xml:21:5-84 duplicated with element declared at 
AndroidManifest.xml:18:5-60
/Users/Dan/Projects/test/testApp/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    Validation failed, exiting


See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.

:processDebugManifest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

If I then remove one of these plugins again, it builds fine. I've tried editing AndroidManifest.xml and removing the duplicate lines, but when I attempt the build they just come back. Is it possible to use these plugins alongside each other?

Thanks for any help.

Edit:

I've also tried removing the line:

`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"/>` from `plugins/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/plugin.xml`

and

`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />` from `plugins/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/plugin.xml`

but this didn't help.

Comment: In `AndroidManifest.xml` declare permission only once. Error is coming due to multiple declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the line:

`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />` from:

`plugins/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/plugin.xml`

This still didn't work, until I ran:

1. `ionic cordova platform rm android`
2. `ionic cordova platform add android`
3. `ionic cordova build android`

Probably not the best solution, but it's working!